# Installed google hangouts plugin, cam not detected

Tags: firefox, webcam

I'm a n00b, so please ELI5 answers.

I was using firefox hello and my cam was working fine, then it muted my video on its own. I closed it and tried to use google hangouts. Had to install the plugin. https://youtu.be/woSjqTVWzec

followed those directions to a t.
Camera still not working. restarted computer
now I have an error
saying i probably have installed packages with unmet dependencies
there is a white light next to the cam that is on constantly that I don't think I have seen before. I am not sure how to run pkg manager. MAYBE I did it right:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgtkglext1 libopencv-calib3d2.4v5 libopencv-contrib2.4v5
  libopencv-core2.4v5 libopencv-features2d2.4v5 libopencv-flann2.4v5
  libopencv-highgui2.4v5 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5 libopencv-legacy2.4v5
  libopencv-ml2.4v5 libopencv-objdetect2.4v5 libopencv-video2.4v5
  libswscale-ffmpeg3 libtbb2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

I have a dell studio 1537, using firefox browser( maybe hangouts works best with chrome? but chrome doesnt work well on here) idk how to see what version of ubuntu I am running, but I just updated it a couple of days ago. These problems are not from the update because the camera has worked since.

Edit:

I clicked on the error button and chose "show updates" it said software manager closed unexpectedly. I hit leave closed and I got this:

```
E:Malformed line 52 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
```

...and it popped up again. I think i saw this in the terminal when I tried to install the plugin the first time.

..i can't find where i got the commands from though for that one. But the camera wasn't working before all that. It had the word canonical in it.

UPDATE

I turned it completely off and on again. Now the white light is gone

here are lines 51-53

oops. I can't post them

I fixed it myself. Camera works and no more error.

Opened up the src code and added a "#" in front of line 52. Rebooted. All good.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Whoo -- a lot of stuff here. The `malformed line` part means something's wrong with your sources file. Look up that error to get the repair instructions. Once you do that, run `sudo apt-get update` in the Terminal, `sudo apt-get upgrade` and then `sudo apt-get install -f`.